# Windows 8.1 phone development licence

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to deploy to a windows 8.1 phone without having a developers licence?

I am trying to build and demo a proof of concept, so buying a licence at this time is not really wanted or required. I have looked through various sites and the Microsoft sites but cannot find a way of deploying the app without a licence.

I would be happy to use the emulator in visual studio but my computer only has 4gb so that is not an option. If I need a licence are there any other temporary options open to me? or are my only options up the RAM or get a licence

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and not programming. If you have questions about licensing, contact the vendor or an attorney licensed to practice in your jurisdiction. This site is for programming related questions as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need a license to 'side load' the application to test devices.